# Django - Displaying model having content type in admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin, django-admin-actions

I am new to Django and I am facing a problem. I have multiple model that require address and phone number against address. And only phone number can be associated with some of models. So, I have made polymorphic relation for "**Addresses**" and "**PhoneNumber**". Like here:

```
class PhoneNumber(SoftDeleteModel):
     phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.phone_number.as_e164

class Address(SoftDeleteModel):
     house_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     street_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
     phone_number = GenericRelation(PhoneNumber)
     content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
          return str(self.house_number)+", "+str(self.street_number)+", "+self.area+", "+self.city+", "+self.country
```

These are the model for **Address** & **PhoneNumber** I am using **Address** model in **Vendor** like:

```
class Vendor(SoftDeleteModel):
     vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     vendor_phone = GenericRelation(PhoneNumber)
     vendor_address_detailed = GenericRelation(Address)
     vendor_contact_person = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.vendor_name
```

When I am making crud in admin for vendor I am able to get only **Addresses** not **PhoneNumber** in **Address** model like in in this picture [image]

And the code for admin classes is below:

```
class PhoneNumberAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
     model = PhoneNumber
     extra = 1
     exclude = ('deleted', 'created_by')

     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         obj.created_by = request.user
         super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)


class AddressAdmin(GenericStackedInline):
     model = Address
     extra = 1
     exclude = ('deleted', 'created_by')

     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         obj.created_by = request.user
         super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)


class VendorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     model = Vendor
     list_display = ('vendor_name', 'created_by', 'created_at_readable')
     inlines = (AddressAdmin, )
     exclude = ('deleted', 'created_by')

     def created_at_readable(self, obj):
         return naturaltime(obj.created_at)

     created_at_readable.empty_value_display = "???"
```

Please help me to add **PhoneNumber** using Django Admin.

**Edit:**

I want to associate phone numbers with each address. So in admin PhoneNumber field will be in Adress model not in Vendor. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After surfing through the web I found this library called NestedAdmin. This library supports almost all kind of nested relations in admin. I am going to post its url here.

https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin

Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

Add the inline of PhoneNumber in VendorAdmin

```
 inlines = (AddressAdmin, PhoneNumberAdmin)
```

Comment: This works but I want PhoneNumberAdmin in Address model to associate multiple numbers with address like : Vendor->Address1->phone1-phone2 etc.